# Accept Terms of Service with one-click button in email

Tags: email

Beside the legal aspect, do you think it is okay to have a one-click link in an e-mail to accept TOS, knowing that the TOS document is an attached PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the email clearly states what clicking the link does, it might be okay but there are many other things to consider. Rather than attaching it as a PDF, include it in the email if possible. Rather than have the link auto accept the TOS, have the link bring to a page that allows the user to view and accept the TOS.

TOS should also be accepted before a user finishes setting up an account, as in, when providing the email, make them accept the terms of service their instead of sending a separate email for accepting terms of service. If they have already accepted it, an email simply notifying them of updated TOS is acceptable.